# PNG Compression Not Reducing the size of images

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, image-compression, mogrify

I have certain png files. They are of size approx 1MB. I tried several command but they didn't work for me. Any suggestions. One is as below :

```
"C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-6.9.9-Q16\\mogrify.exe" -depth 8 -format png -define PNG:compression-strategy=2 -define PNG:compression-filter=0 test.png
```

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried Glenn's [pngcrush](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pngcrush)?

Comment: No, Is that free? If pngcrush also works for jpeg file?

Comment: Perhaps your PNG file is already compressed. It would be a good idea to post a link to your file. You should also try using convert rather than mogrify. Mogrify is not a flexible as convert. See also -quality values for PNG at https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#quality. I do not think pngcrush works on jpg files.

Comment: PNG files often compress better if you reduce the number of colours - if that is an option for you. By the way, your `-format png` is superfluous if your image is already a PNG.

Comment: I tried convert also with quality 80. Still have minor decrease. In case we want to reduce colors. What should be the idle command with least distortion. I am just learning these compression framework. Hence your help really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @fmw42 in comments, your image may already be optimized. Also, @Mark's comment regarding reducing colors is true.

But apart from this, the important thing to know is that "there is no ideal command". You will have to figure out bit depth in your color channels and reduce them. There will always be a trade-off between reducing colors and quality you wish to pick.

Apart from that, there can also be other methods that you can use:

1. If opacity of PNG is fully opaque, you can strip alpha channel as it
   makes no sense in that case. This can give you some file size savings.
2. If the image is visibly grayscale and still color type is
   true-color, true-color-alpha or indexed-color, you can make significant savings by saving the image with a grayscale color space.
3. Retry optimizing PNG files using adaptive delta filtering and LZ77 Optimizations. This can be done easily using "[optipng](http://optipng.sourceforge.net/)". But if the image is already optimized enough, this won't provide significant file sizes reduction. Moreover, choice of filtering depends upon png bit depths, so you would have to look up and understand PNG compression from various documentation available online regarding PNG compression.